# rails]Simple Inquiry About References Between Two Models

Tags: model, relation

I have Post and Comment models, and now I want to create User model.
User has_many posts, and post belongs_to user. When I created Comment model with a generator, I used *post:references,* so Is it required for me to **add user_id column to Post model** manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

```
rails generate migration AddUserIdToPosts user_id:integer
```

and manually put *belongs_to user* in Post model.

Comment: also when you create a new object, you have to remember referring to the right related model. ex) post = Post.new -> post.user_id = {some user}